# EMQ 3.0 deployed on AWS unable to receive 4kb mqtt data

Tags: amazon-ec2, emq

I deployed EMQ 3.0 on AWS Ec2 instance and configured it mostly with default configuration but I changed buffer sizes as my requirement is to send an MQTT data of 4KB. But it is not working and EMQ broker is not receving the message.  Is there any restriction on packet size on AWS side and if so how to increase it? I verified that EMQ configuration allows a packet up 64kb and I increased external buffer size to 4KB without success.
Any sugestions or approach to fix this issue? Please note that I am able to send data upto 2KB.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any restriction on packet size on AWS side and if so how to increase it?**

> There is no such packet size restriction from AWS (EC2) side,
>   according to shared responsibility model.

The problem with the Web-Sockets support which means that messages with large payloads or special payload size do not reach the EMQ code responsible for implementing broker behavior, so changing .conf **max_packet_size** has no effect in this case.

Bug fix link https://github.com/emqx/emqx/issues/643